# Access mp4 file on windows server 2008 R2 says access denied

Tags: video, video-streaming, access-denied, windows-server

I have stored some images (.jpg) and videos (.mp4) on windows server 2008 R2.

When I access website say,
http://wbsite public ip/newAudit/auditmultimedia/checklists/2785/0418e263-d722-4a30-999f-fd5c5ff54212.jpg
crome shows me the image no problem.

But when I try to access video same way,
http://wbsite public ip/newAudit/auditmultimedia/checklists/2785/test.mp4
It shows me message,
404 - File or Directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Images and videos are in same folder. I can access image but not video.
I have give fill control to "Everyone" for these directories and files.

### So how can I access .mp4 file on my browser.

Actually I want to access this video in IOS app on iPad. But I can not play above video in IOS app but I can show image in that same app.

Comment: Does mp4 have a mime type set up for it on the server?

Comment: yes thanks Sami. that was not set in config file.. I added it in config file and now can see video.